# pgSql not pulling all data for a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query against Postgres database some how leaves few rows for the date: 2017-10-01.  I have added time zone also. Is there a way to solve this issues?

```
select min(p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone AT TIME ZONE 'America/Phoenix') as Date, 
    'America/Phoenix' AS Timezone, sum(GREATEST(0, p.value)) as Value, p.uom as UnitOfMeasurement   
from main.production_ts_2017_10 p                                  
where p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone >= to_date('2017-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD') +  INTERVAL '2 day' 
    and p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone <= '2017-10-30'
    and p.serial_number = '5T7842974Z'                  
group by date_trunc('hour', p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone AT TIME ZONE 'America/Phoenix'), p.uom   
order by Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify it down to just this part of the query:

```
p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone >= to_date('2017-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD') +  INTERVAL '2 day'
```

This is a conditional expression around the `>=` operator. It has a left-hand side (`p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone`) and a right-hand side: (`to_date('2017-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD') +  INTERVAL '2 day'`) that are each evaluated separately, so the final conditional result (true/false) can be determined for each record.

> Postgres database some how leaves few rows for the date: 2017-10-01

Look again at the right-hand side of the expression:

```
to_date('2017-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD') +  INTERVAL '2 day'
```

That reduces down to this value:

```
'2017-10-02'
```

In other words, you're limited to records that come after '2017-10-01'. Do you really want that `INTERVAL` section in there? Did you want to subtract two days instead of add?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume two things:

1. You're asking "why does this query show a few rows for October 1st when it should show only rows for October 2nd or later"
2. p.start_timestamp is of type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE (I feel safe in assuming this, because otherwise the double-timezone casting of it in other parts of the query makes no sense).

You have this WHERE clause:

```
where p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone >= to_date('2017-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD') +  INTERVAL '2 day'
```

Now, the left-hand side of the query is `p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone` which will evaluate to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.  The right-hand side of the query, however, is `to_date('2017-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD') +  INTERVAL '2 day'` which evaluates to a TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE.

Whenever you compare a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE to a TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE, the results are going to be dependent on your current TimeZone setting in your psql session, because the TIMESTAMP-no-TZ will be evaluated as if it is in the psql TimeZone.  For example, 12:31AM in 'America/Phoenix' on October 2nd can be 11:31AM in 'America/Los_Angeles', depending on the date (and BTW, you chose the worst possible time zone as your default, because America/Phoenix is just wierd).  This would result in you seeing records from October 1st, depending on the value of p.timezone.

You're compounding the problem with this:

```
select min(p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone AT TIME ZONE 'America/Phoenix') as Date
```

... so now you're displaying all timestamps as America/Phoenix timestamps regardless of what timezone they were originally in, or what timezone they were compared with.  If your TimeZone setting is UTC, you'll see a LOT of October 1st records, because Oct 2nd in UTC overlaps with Oct 1st in America/Phoenix for six or seven hours depending on the date.

I suspect, given the rest of the query, what you want for that WHERE clause is:

```
where ( p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone ) 
       >= 
      ( to_date('2017-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD') +  INTERVAL '2 day' ) 
      AT TIME ZONE 'America/Phoenix'
      AND p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone 
       <= 
      ( TIMESTAMP '2017-10-30' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Phoenix' )
```

All of this is an illustrative lesson in why you should be storing all of your timestamp data as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, instead of what you're doing here.  As long as you're storing the timezone in a separate field an using AT TIME ZONE all the time, you're going to keep breaking queries.  Also, with all of this casting time zones, any indexes you have on those time columns are unlikely to be used.